# Copying a subset of a large folder, preferably using robocopy

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy

I want to copy some files from a huge share on a high-latency server. I can do it with multiple `robocopy` commands:

```
robocopy /MT \\slow\share\path1 c:\my\path1 *.exe
robocopy /MT \\slow\share\path2 c:\my\path2 *.pdb
etc.
```

However, I'd like to do it with a single `robocopy`, since then I can use `/MT` to speed up the copying. However, I couldn't find a way to do this with robocopy:

```
robocopy /MT \\slow\share c:\my path1\*.exe path2\*.pdb
```

This results in `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "path1\*.exe"`

```
robocopy /MT \\slow\share *.exe *.pdb
```

This copies all of `path2\*.exe` which I don't want, and also traverses all of \slow\share, which is slow.

Is there any other way, ideally using a built-in command?

Comment: @Jonathin Have you looked at RichCopy ? Maybe you can tweak it to do some of this. It has interesting conditional inclusions and exclusions in advanced mode.

Comment: [RichCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) looks interesting - you can indeed specify multiple source dirs. However, since it's a GUI program, I can't use it in a script - because the script will continue before RichCopy is finished.

Comment: What kind of script are you using? Batch or Powershell?

Comment: I think this might be a tough one, as even though RoboCopy has multi threaded support thats internally managed. It does not allow 'parameters'
for "multi-Source" copying. Also scripting environments are typically sequential, unless they specifically allow/enable parallel -forks. So, by the looks of it, you need both or atleast one of them.

Comment: I haven't decided on an env yet. I guess I'll use PowerShell and its `invoke-command -AsJob` async capabilities. I hoped robocopy/whatever could save me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue, I want to mirror files from one location to another. When I was looking for copying software I got truly bizarre applications that would integrate them self into your windows shell. But then I started to search for Syncing software and got a much better array of application.

I have tested two products

1. [ViceVersa](http://www.tgrmn.com/)
2. [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)

Both applications are GUI and have the ability to script batch files for them. Both allow for multiple source/target. They have the ability to Mirror, Dual Sync, Augment Target and versioning.

ViceVersa is wonderful, but comes with a price tag. FreeFileSync is just as good as ViceVersa, but I haven't had a chance to fully test it. Reading the things it can do from it's webpage sure looks like is surpasses ViceVersa's abilities.

Comment: Good info. Eventually I needed to access some API that tells me when&where the files are, so I ended up writing the whole thing in C#, where I have all the parallelism control I can possibly want.